# Hive - Reformat data structure

Tags: sql, json, hive, hiveql

So I have a sample of Hive data:

| Customer | xx_var | yy_var | branchflow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"customer_no":"239230293892839892","acct":["2324325","23425345"]} | 23 | 3 | [{"acctno":"2324325","value":[1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,4]},{"acctno":"23425345","value":[1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,99,4]}] |

And I want to transform it into something like this:

| Customer_no | acct | xx_var | yy_var | branchflow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 239230293892839892 | 2324325 | 23 | 3 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,4] |
| 239230293892839892 | 23425345 | 23 | 3 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,99,4] |

I have tried using this query, but getting the wrong output format.

```
SELECT 
    customer.customer_no,
    acct,
    xx_var,
    yy_var,
    bi_acctno,
    values_bi
FROM
    struct_test 
LATERAL VIEW explode(customer.acct) acct AS acctno
LATERAL VIEW explode(brancflow.acctno) bia as bi_acctno
LATERAL VIEW explode(brancflow.value) biv as values_bi
WHERE bi_acctno = acctno
```

Does anyone know how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use json_tuple to extract JSON elements. In case of array, it returns it also as string: remove square brackets, split and explode. See comments in the demo code.

Demo:

```
with mytable as (--demo data, use your table instead of this CTE
select '{"customer_no":"239230293892839892","acct":["2324325","23425345"]}' as customer,    
       23 xx_var,   3 yy_var,   
       '[{"acctno":"2324325","value":[1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,4]},{"acctno":"23425345","value":[1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,99,4]}]' branchflow
)

select c.customer_no, 
       a.acct,  
       t.xx_var,    t.yy_var, 
       get_json_object(b.acct_branchflow,'$.value') value
  from mytable t
       --extract customer_no and acct array
       lateral view json_tuple(t.customer, 'customer_no', 'acct') c as customer_no, accts
       --remove [] and " and explode array of acct
       lateral view explode(split(regexp_replace(c.accts,'^\\[|"|\\]$',''),',')) a as acct
       --remove [] and explode array of json
       lateral view explode(split(regexp_replace(t.branchflow,'^\\[|\\]$',''),'(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)')) b as acct_branchflow
--this will remove duplicates after lateral view: need only matching acct
 where get_json_object(b.acct_branchflow,'$.acctno') = a.acct
```

Result:

```
customer_no         acct        xx_var  yy_var  value
239230293892839892  2324325     23      3       [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,4]
239230293892839892  23425345    23      3       [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,99,4]
```